# WSL is enabled on windows 10 but Linux.exe errors that it is not enabled

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run **ubuntu1804.exe** for having "Linux distros for WSL", I receive this:

```
The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. Please enable it and try again.
See https://aka.ms/wslinstall for details.
Press any key to continue...
```

But, it is enabled on my Windows:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux


Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

And here is the screenshot of optional features window:

[image: Image of Optional feature]

What sould I do to solve this? would appreciate any assistance.

P.S: I tried "disabling WSL, rebooting, Enabling WSL, rebooting" but not working.

Comment: Which Windows 10 build you're using?

Comment: What is `ubuntu1804.exe`? I start WSL by typing `bash` in a Windows command prompt.

Comment: Oh, you want to start a GUI. Which Desktop Environment? How did you set it up?

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux has not been in Beta for over a year (1703).  You should upgrade to 1803 then install the Ubuntu WSL instance from the Windows Store instead of using the legacy instance your currently using.  *Windows 10 Version 1607 is not compatible with the instance your trying to use.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My windows version and also Windows Subsystem version is **OLD** so it is not compatible.
It must be upgraded.